# nodejs: short alias for process.stdout.write

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning nodejs (and I like it!). I tried to figure out how to have shorter alias for `console.log` and I found out that I can use `var cout=console.log` and use `cout('[string]')` from then on. Then when I wanted to use `process.stdout.write` and I tried to make a short alias for it too, using `var out=process.stdout.write`. But when I use `out('[string]')`, I get the following error:

> _stream_writable.js:220   var state = this._writableState;
>                     ^   TypeError: Cannot read property '_writableState' of undefined
>
> at Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:220:19)
>       at Socket.write (net.js:670:40)
>       at Object. (/home/shayan/Desktop/nodejs/server.js:12:1)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)

What is wrong here?
How can I correctly create a short alias for `process.stdout.write`?
Thanks

Comment: This is an underrated question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not do this kind of "short alias". It's very messy and people reading your code won't understand why you use random function names instead of `console.log`. However, if you really want to create function aliases, consider using a `function`:

```
function out(text) {
    //    ^    ^- argument accepted by the function
    //    |------ the function name
    process.stdout.write(text)
    //                     ^- pass the argument you accepted in your new function to the long function
}
```

I added some explanation in case you don't know how a function works, you can safely remove it.

**Edit:**
The reason why it's not working is in the source code of Node.JS. The stacktrace you are getting back points to [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_writable.js#L236) line:

```
Writable.prototype.write = function(chunk, encoding, cb) {
    var state = this._writableState;
    // ...
}
```

It tries to reference a variable called `_writableState` from `this`. As written [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context):

> Inside a function, the value of `this` depends on how the function is called.

This means, that `this` refers to `process.stdout` when you call `process.stdout.write`, however it is undefined, when you call it from your alias. Therefore you get a `Cannot read property '_writableState' of undefined` exception (as `undefined` does not contain that variable, which is important for the `write` function to execute).

Comment: Well, I was hoping I could gain some insight on why the method I explained works for console.log and not for process.stdout.write. Also, does the fact that you suggested a function, mean there is no way to give a short alias to process.stdout.write? That's weird! But as you said, code readability strongly suggests not to use these methods anyway. And I upvoted your answer, but because I'm new, my votes aren't visible!

Comment: @Credo I updated my answer to give a bit more detail. Feel free to ask if something is not clear.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from a function declaration you can also use `Function.prototype.bind`:

```js
const out = process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout);
out('foo');
```

`bind` returns a new function with the context (`this`) bound to whatever value you pass.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: This is a really good answer! So the 'problem' is that it's a method and it does not see the original parent object when you try to snatch it impolitely. :D

Comment: Can agree with AturSams, I had the same problem where I was getting `TypeError: Cannot read property '_writableState' of undefined` but this was with socket.write with the npm module, "net". I was trying to use socket.write in a function although this failed due to Benni's answer's explanation. Great answer and helped me with my different scenario!