# node.js process.stdout.write TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdout

I am working on a simple function to create console-based prompts in node.js without the use of a bunch of extra libraries:

“““

```
function prompt(text, callback) { // Text can be a question or statement.
    'use strict';
    var input, output;

    process.stdout.write(text + ' ');
    process.stdin.addListener('readable', function read() { // Stream type *must* be correct!
        input = process.stdin.read();
        if (input) { // Wait for actual input!
            output = input.toString().slice(0, -2); // Slicing removes the trailing newline, an artifact of the 'readable' stream type.
            process.stdout.write('You typed: ' + output);
            process.stdin.pause(); // Stops waiting for user input, else the listener keeps firing.
            callback(output);
        }
    });
}

prompt('Enter some text:', process.stdout.write);
// Enter some text: x
// You typed: x_stream_writable.js:200
//   var state = this.writableState;
//
// TypeError: Cannot read property '_writableState' of undefined
//     ...
```

”””

As per the question [nodejs: shore alias for process.stdout.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362222/nodejs-shore-alias-for-process-stdout-write) , the “““`this`””” can be undefined when called from an alias. However, I am not using aliases, but direct calls of “““`process.stdout.write`”””. The first instance, inside the “““`read()`””” function, works fine but the second instance, as part of the callback, does not. Even weirder is that “““`console.log`””” works just fine if I substitute it in the second instance at the callback, despite it supposedly being a mere wrapper for the “““`process.stdout.write`””” function. How can I bind a “““`this`””” to the string “““`output`””” or, if that that isn’t feasible, what else can I do to solve the error “““`TypeError: Cannot read property '_writableState' of undefined`”””?

Comment: If the goal is to prompt the user for input, why not *at least* use the built-in [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/readline.html) module instead of trying to do it all manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `process.stdout.write()` is called, it is expecting to be bound to the `process.stdout` object.

You can simply bind the function passed as the callback:

```
prompt('Enter some text:', process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout));
```

In addition, your input `slice(0,-2)` does not work on Linux (as the newline is only one character '\n' instead of Windows '\r\n') - it's probably easier just to use `input.toString().trim()`  or look up `os.EOL` for a more OS-agnostic approach.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried binding to “““`process.stdout.write`””” but that wasn’t quite it—for whatever reason, I just don’t end up using “““`bind`””” or “““`this`””” in any *\*any\** of my programs so this adjustment was exactly what I needed. And thanks for the reminder about the Unix-likes’s different EOLs—“““`trim()`””” is indeed the better way to go.