# Can't get process.stdout.write... to work

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use `process.stdout.write("some text");` to print text without terminating `\n`.
Under Visual Studio Code debugger I am getting an error:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'write')`

The code included:

```
    const s1 = of(1, 2, 3).pipe(
    map(v1 =>
      of(100, 101, 102, 103, 104).pipe(
        map(v2 => [v1,v2])
      )
    ),
    combineLatestAll()
  );
  s1.subscribe(value => {
    process.stdout.write("["+value+"]");
  });
```

Has anybody encountered this issue?

Comment: Please include the code where that error occurs.

Comment: Done. Please see above in original question.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779767/node-js-process-stdout-write-typeerror?

Comment: Do you mean replace the call `process.stdout.write("["+value+"]");` by `prompt("["+value+"]", process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout));` ?

Comment: I mean process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout)("["+value+"]")

Comment: I got same error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'write')`.                                                                                                                                       Under Visual Studio code IDE it does not show any errors, but when I run debugger in Visual Studio Code IDE that's when it shows the error.

Comment: #Peter Any other suggestions. I really need to get this to work.

Comment: I will take a look again when I reach my laptop.

Comment: I debugged your code in my VS Code, but the error did not occur.  My VS Code version:  .65.2 and node version: 16.13.0

Comment: My VS Code version: is 1..65.1 and node version: 14.16.0.- read from Help/About dialog box of VS Code.  When I run command `ng version` it says 16.13.0. I don't know why is this discrepancy. How do I upgrade the node version used by VS Code?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem I have the same discrepancy between my Vs Code and my terminal.

Comment: Hi Peter. I posted new thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71522241/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-read-in-visual-stud) where I referred also to the video I followed to get it to work, but without success.

Comment: I think you might want to go to VS Code Github repo and open an issue there.

Comment: I did and they closed the issue immediately saying that "It is a question about using VS Code rather than an issue or feature request". They suggested I search for help on StackOverflow.

Comment: Apparently you can’t use the `process` in the browser – see the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71522241/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-read-in-visual-stud