# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'read')" in Visual Studio Code Debugger

Tags: javascript, angular

Visual Studio Code Version 1.65.1
Node: 16.13.0
Angular: 13.0.3
Platform: Windows 10

When I am trying to use in my angular project:

```
process.stdout.write("some text");
```

... I am getting in the debugger of VSC IDE the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'write')`. I have done some research:
I have added into my tsconfig.app.json `"types": ["node"]` as suggested in other thread.
I have followed the video [Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined , Angular 12,13 Error Fixed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_mphZilfw4) to add to the polyfills.ts `(window as any).process = {env: {DEBUG: undefined},};` and it compiles OK, but I am getting this error during debug session.

Comment: using process.stdout.white might work duing building SSR or building the project cause you are in Node space, but as soon as you are in the browser you no longer has access to Node it self. you are now in browser space.

Comment: What  do you mean by SSR. I just want to use `process.stdout.write` in my debugger.

Comment: SSR is server side rendering. and hence it is run on a node server. But as soon as it has been served to the client it is run in the browser where you no longer has access to process

Comment: I only need to use it in VSC IDE though - locally for debugging purpose.

Comment: Are you saying I can't use it even when using VSC IDE debugger?

Comment: Yeah basically. If you want to log anything to console use the default console.log command. Not sure if it captures that in the IDE, but i would assume it would, cause it just connects the browser debugger with the ide.